# MS ACCESS = VBA checking between dates?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to get a static date of 7/1/YYYY (YYYY being sent by the year function), to evaluate between two dates and tell me if the certification date is between them or not.

So the business problem for our non profit is this. Each year, the client must sign a form by 7/1/YYYY. So if they sign one in june, they only get a few days/weeks before they have to sign again after 7/1. The biggest problem right now is getting the dynamic year to work when the year turns over to the next.[Screenshot of the issue with code when year turnover is simulated by changing the computers date on the system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehrvz.png)

I've tried this below (updated to be more DRY, thanks to xShen!), but it fails when the year turns over to the next year.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()


   Dim Curtefapdate As Date
   Dim Pretefapdate As Date

   Pretefapdate = DateSerial(Year(Date) - 1, 7, 1)
   Curtefapdate = DateSerial(Year(Date), 7, 1)
If Not IsDate(Me.TEFAP_Date) Or Me.TEFAP_Date <= Curtefapdate Then
 DoCmd.SetProperty "recertreqwarn", acPropertyVisible, "-1"
 Beep
 MsgBox "TEFAP is out of date: " & Me.TEFAP_Date & " compared to a recert date of: " & Curtefapdate & ", please update now....", vbOKOnly, "Update TEFAP, Current Certification Period of " & Pretefapdate & " - " & Curtefapdate

End If
  
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried using `DateDiff`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datediff-function

Comment: You want fiscal begin and end? If current month is greater than 6, add 1 to current year to get ending year, if month is less than 7 subtract 1 from year to get beginning year.

Comment: So the business problem for our non profit is this. Each year, the client must sign a form by 7/1/YYYY. So if they sign one in june, they only get a few days/weeks before they have to sign again after 7/1. The biggest problem right now is getting the dynamic year to work when the year turns over to the next.

Answer (score 1):

You could make your code much simpler.

```
dim ....
Pretefapdate2 =DateSerial ( year(date)-1,7,1)
Curtefapdate2  = DateSerial( year(date),7,1)
If Not IsDate(Me.TEFAP_Date) Or Me.TEFAP_Date <= Curtefapdate2 Then
' your code ..
end if
```

Comment: you're awesome, this code is definitely more DRY. Thank you! I mostly program in JS, didn't think to use DateSerial. So the solution solves all business cases except this one "When the year turns over and we're in jan 2024, the code dynamically updates the the curtefapdat2 being 7/1/2024, causing the attached issue come jan.

Comment: here is the revised code based on your feedback!

Dim Curtefapdate As Date
Dim Pretefapdate As Date


Pretefapdate = DateSerial(Year(Date) - 1, 7, 1)
Curtefapdate = DateSerial(Year(Date), 7, 1)
If Not IsDate(Me.TEFAP_Date) Or Me.TEFAP_Date <= Curtefapdate Then
 DoCmd.SetProperty "recertreqwarn", acPropertyVisible, "-1"
 Beep
 MsgBox "TEFAP is out of date: " & Me.TEFAP_Date & " compared to a recert date of: " & Curtefapdate & ", please update now....", vbOKOnly, "Update TEFAP, Current Certification Period of " & Pretefapdate & " - " & Curtefapdate

End If

Comment: I finally solved it with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `DateAdd` to shift the dates to the calendar year:

```
If IsNull(Me!TEFAP_Date.Value) Or Year(DateAdd("m", 6, Nz(Me!TEFAP_Date.Value, Date)) < Year(DateAdd("m", 6, Date)) Then
```